# How can I set a custom Controltemplate as the default for whole application?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I have decided to look at trying to customize a number of aspects of the default control template for Menu and MenuItem. In Visual Studio, I selected my Menu, found 'Template' in the property panel, and chose 'Convert to New Resource...'.

I did the same thing for MenuItem. Then, just to test, I changed the MenuItem SubMenuBorder color to red. At this point, I had a resource dictionary with the two ControlTemplates, and a Menu that looked like this:

```
<Menu Template="{DynamicResource CustomMenuControlTemplate}">
    <MenuItem Header="File" Template="{DynamicResource CustomMenuItemControlTemplate}">
        <MenuItem Header="Test 1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Test 2">
            <MenuItem Header="Subtest 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Subtest 2" />
            <MenuItem Header="Subtest 3" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Test 3" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image: Menu 1]

The issue is that the red border will only appear on MenuItems where I explicitly set the Template to my modified CustomMenuItemControlTemplate. If I want to have my template used on all menu items, I would have to include:

```
Template="{DynamicResource CustomMenuItemControlTemplate}"
```

...on every MenuItem in my entire application.

So, next I thought that I'd have a style that applies to all MenuItems, and use a setter to set my default template:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource CustomMenuItemControlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

This works (note the red borders on all sub-menus), but for some reason, it drastically changes how the menus look:

[image: Menu 2]

In that setter, I tried using both DynamicResource and StaticResource bindings, with the same results.

So, my main question: Is there a way to use a custom ControlTemplate as the default, so that I don't have to explicitly set it on each control? Secondary question: Why does using a style to set the template property cause such drastic changes to how it looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question:

If you put the ControlTemplate in your app.xaml's resource dictionary, it will be applied across your entire application. Your control template header should have something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem" ...(other properties)>
```

This will make all MenuItem controls implicitly use that control template.

To answer you second question:

This occurs because adding a style overrides the default style, essentially removing all built-in styling. If you want the style to only change a few things the style tag should look like this:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" ...(other properties)>
```

This way it inherits all the normal styling and just changes the styles you explicitly define

Comment: That makes sense to me, now... especially about how it's overriding the default style. That said, I tried adding the control template to my app.xaml without a key, and I get the same error as when I tried that in a resource dictionary 'Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.' Can you please explain exactly where it should go? I put it inside the app.xaml ResourceDictionary tags.

Comment: You can still have a key, the code I put in my answer was only the important properties that handled your question. Feel free to change any other properties in the tag. If you are wondering why you have a tag and a TargetType, the TargetType handles implicity templating whereas Key can be used for explicity templating of other control types. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I edited my code to make it a little clearer for you or anyone who stumbles upon it

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Unfortunately, it seems you cannot have the ControlTemplate as a resource without providing a key. As a result of that, it is not used implicitly, even when you do set the TargetType. With the key, you have to set bind the template property using that key. In addition, the explanation that you provided about the BasedOn makes sense. Using BasedOn, howerver, just seems to cause some even more odd impacts on the layout. I'll be doing a bit more reading on BasedOn before I revise my question. Thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: I believe you can also set the x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" and that should keep the template working implicitly. If that works I will edit my answer. If that doesn't work you can copy the control template once into each view's xaml file and that way you won't need to specify x:Key

Comment: You cannot put a type as a key.  This answer does not address the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

So you can't put a control template without a key, and the key can't be `{x:Type ...}` in WPF.

But you can put a `Style` without a key, and that style will be the default. -- And in that style, you can set the control template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <!-- Insert Control Template Here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer